# Android Studio Fix Layout Files from BSOD Crash

Tags: android, android-studio

My pc went into BSOD state and when I open my project I get broken files :

For example in my activity.xml, it's showing this:

```
<component name="ProjectCodeStyleConfiguration">
  <state>
    <option name="USE_PER_PROJECT_SETTINGS" value="true" />
  </state>
</component>
```

When I go file explorer and open the activity.xml file itself, the content is fine

How do I fix this?